# table, chart, diagram, form, graph

Tags: differences, vocabulary

What's the difference between these words? If possible, give some examples for each please. Thank you very much.

Collins Dictionary:

table: A table is a written set of facts and figures arranged in columns and rows

chart: A chart is a diagram, picture, or graph which is intended to make information easier to understand.

diagram: A diagram is a simple drawing which consists mainly of lines and is used, for example, to explain how a machine works.

form:  A form is a paper with questions on it and spaces marked where you should write the answers.

graph: A graph is a mathematical diagram which shows the relationship between two or more sets of numbers or measurements.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to link to the definitions you've looked up, and which part of those definitions (or which part of the differences among those definitions) are still unclear. This would help the community to address the specific issues you're working through with this set of words.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be in English Language Learners?

Comment: Have you tried Google images, they say a picture paints a thousand words. Failing that there's always Wikipedia: [**chart**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart), [**diagram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram), [**table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(information)#/media/File:Table-sample-appearance-default-params-values-01.gif) etc. scroll down the pages to see more examples.

Comment: Thank you @Lawrence@David@Mari-Lou A. Btw, can you provide the link of English Language Learners, pls? Thank you :)

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're welcome. Do the definitions clear up the differences among the words for you?